# Get column in a row in a table if that row has a selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table like the following

```
<table id="adminTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Email</th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='selected_users[]' value='User1'/></td><td>User1</td><td>mail1@mail.com</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='selected_users[]' value='User2'/></td><td>User2</td><td>mail2@mail.com</td></tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have a button below which calls a javascript-function.
This function then should get all the emails for the users which were selected via their checkboxes...

I am quite new to Javascript and jQuery an am not sure of how to achieve this...
But I can use plain Javascript or use jQuery...

What I already found was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/), but I can't get it to help me, because I don't want a button in my row (multiple selections shall be possible via the checkboxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#adminTable").find("td").filter(function() 
{ 
    return $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0;
});
```

Keep in mind you have TR tags in your html that don't have closing tags and are out of place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function which run on a button click:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    var emails = $("input[name=selected_users[]]:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).closest("td").next("td").text();
    }).get();

    console.log(emails); //array of emails that were checked
});
```